# Reading an image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to read an image in flutter into a Uint8List but it keeps returning file not found even after ive added the asset path in pubspec file

```
Future<Uint8List> pick_default_image() async {
  Uint8List img = (await rootBundle.load('assets/logo_oinkgram.png')).buffer.asUint8List();
  return img;
}

pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? _file = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

  if (_file != Null) {
    return await _file!.readAsBytes();
  }
}





//The variable
  Future<Uint8List>  _image = pick_default_image();
```

Here's the code and error i'm getting:
[Code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzosp.png)\

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path =
> 'assets/logo_oinkgram.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno
> = 2)

any suggestions on what do I do?

edit:

I've updated the functions but the functions applied on the variable are now of different types Future and Uint8List

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access asset files using the `dart:io` library, because assets are bundled with the application and are not part of the device's file system. You should use the `rootBundle` from `package:flutter/services.dart` instead to read the asset data.

Modifing your `pick_default_image()` function like this should work:

```
Future<Uint8List> pick_default_image() async {
  Uint8List img = (await rootBundle.load('assets/logo_oinkgram.png')).buffer.asUint8List();
  return img;
}
```

And don't forget to import `package:flutter/services.dart`.

Comment: This code works but i'm prompted with the error can't assign Future <Uint8List> to Uint8List type and i'm using another function which updates the same variable which has a Uint8List return type

Comment: Is the other function marked as `async` and are you awaiting the `Future<Uint8List>` `pick_default_image()` returns?

Comment: yes, i've updated both the functions in the post